# Bootstrap button border-radius produces white border artifacts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Recently I noticed weird artifacts in my Bootstrap buttons borders. After a while I realized that this is not related with my style and theme, because the artifacts can be reproduced even on the [Bootstrap button documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/buttons/) (just set the border-radius for .btn to 0.15rem)

- The artifacts rendered around the whole border (or a bit inner) if the style sets border-radius for example to 0.15rem.
- I can reproduce it both the latest Chrome and Edge.
- I can reproduce it both the Bootstrap 4 doc page and Bootstrap 5 doc page
- The most weirdest thing that the pixels are random, when I hover over an out of the buttons, the patterns seems to be change, not deterministic.

**Question**

Is this a know error, or reproducible by others, or just me?

[image]

**Magnified**

[image]

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 0.15rem !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
```

Comment: Changed the zoom to 500x, still appears fine. Could be an issue with your monitor? 0.15rem is already 2.4px (with default 1rem = 16px) which is a fraction, zooming it makes it worse. Maybe your monitor has an issue with displaying the fraction of the pixel?

Comment: No problem here either. Firefox Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Chrome latest on Win10. You may be seeing something related to your hardware (graphics card).

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the hardware acceleration off, fixed it for me.

chrome://settings/system

Comment: Many thx. I can live with it, but for our clients will not be clear, that we have nothing to do with it...